# Add footer with jsPDF newest html plugin (NOT fromHTML)

Tags: jspdf

I'm creating a pdf from my page using this code

```
var root = document.getElementById("pdfRoot");
var pdfDoc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
pdfDoc.html(root, {
    callback: function(pdf) {
        pdf.save("my.pdf");
    }
});
```

I don't know how to add a footer that repeats on all my pages. All solutions I find apply to the old unsupported fromHTML/addHTML plugins.
If I just add a <footer> in my "pdfRoot" div, it doesn't repeat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Footer to pdf using jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515127/adding-footer-to-pdf-using-jspdf)

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1340 or [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/okwxsY6IuDlKLMxOtUd8/)

Comment: Thank you @Durga for your replies but this is not a duplicate as I'm not interested in a generic way of adding a footer: I want to do it using the new jsPDF.html plugin, which is not addressed anywhere.

Comment: @Durga the plunker link you sent me generates an empty pdf.