# How to add img as footer and header to my PDF with jspdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, jspdf

I know the answer might be inside the files of jspdf folder but is just that I can't find.
I need to add footer and header to my pdf according to files uploaded to my index, the thing is that I can't find the function of jspdf that adds Footer and Header to the PDF and how to call it

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function newPDF(someText){
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(someText, 10, 10);
      doc.save('sample.pdf');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What you mean by footer and header? text to your pdf doc?

Comment: Answer? [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515127/adding-footer-to-pdf-using-jspdf) -

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear, I mean Footer and Header with an IMG (Like my logo)